# CloudFront cache invalidation for React app

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cloudfront

I have a React/redux app which is deployed on CloudFront + s3. There is no static hosting enabled on the bucket. I understand that invalidating cache on a new deployment clears cache in all the edge locations and the new changes will be served up. But what happens to the active prod users when the cache is invalidated? Are they able to continue on the app without any errors? Does it get worse for the active users if the redux store structure changed in the new version?

Comment: There wont be any impact on active users after old cache gets invalidated. Remember, Bundled js file will be downloaded once from server from there until you refresh your browser your react/redux app will use your old app (app before cache got invalidated). Also there would some issues if there are changes in your backend services

Comment: I disagree with @NageshDhope - there can be issues with chunk files that are loaded on demand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the cloudfront cache will bring up the fresh content from your origin. However, that would not affect the existing production users. They would continue to be served from the cached content as long as their session continues.

That being said, they would be served the fresh content when their session restarts. 
There would be no errors whatsoever.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have chunks instead of a single bundled is. In a React app Wouldn’t the chunks be incompatible between routes for old VS new chunks especially if the redux store structure changed betweeen deployment versions?

Comment: I've run into an issue with chunks, where the old files were removed + cache invalidated during a deployment. An active user on the website tried to load a chunk but it was missing. So the user was forced to refresh the website to get the latest version. One potential fix would be to leave old files in S3 for about a year.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wondering the same thing for my React website, which is made up of many chunks. I wouldn't worry about your Redux state unless you're saving it to cookie/localstorage and loading it again. In that case you could write some migration check during loading. Or even have it versioned in some way.

Regarding caching, I don't recommend deleting any files for up to a year. That way your active users would still be able to download chunks while they're active on your website.

During deployment I upload all the new files and clear the cache on all *.html files to get the latest reference to js and css files.